# 'Environments' button missing in Remix IDE new install

Tags: solidity, remix

I just installed Remix IDE, and I'm trying to follow a tutorial for writing smart contracts. The very first step says to click the *Environments* button in Remix. However, that button is missing from the start page. I only have *File, Featured Plugins*, and *Resources*. The only place I see any Environments is when I click the icon for Deploy and Run transactions, there is an Environment dropdown box. However this box is missing the one I need, which is the Solidity environment. This box only contains Javascipt VM, Injected Web3 and Web3 provider. How do I fix this install of Remix?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial seems to be outdated. "Javascript VM" is the current name of the previously called "Solidity environment", for at least a year now.

Mind that the tutorial might also be using a specific version of Solidity, that would probably be now deprecated. The current version (May 2021) is 0.8.4, you can find breaking changes between versions in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/080-breaking-changes.html).

Comment: Thank you, I understand I must be more careful about research. You are correct, the tutorial I referenced was from August 2020 and has since been superseded; the new tutorial does match my environment. My Remix installation is the latest version 1.1.0, so I'm ok there. Appreciate the response!